# Finite existence of the integral

Tags: real-analysis

I have the domain $\Omega_{\alpha}=\{(x,y,t): x^2+y^2\le e^{\alpha t}, t\ge 0\}$
and I want find for which $\alpha\ge0$ exists finited $\int_{\Omega_{\alpha}}{{x^2+t^2}\over{1+x^2+y^2}}dx dy dt$.

I use a change of coordinates:$x=r \sin \theta,y=r \cos \theta, t=t$
so i calculate :$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{e^{{\alpha t}\over {2}}} {{r^2{{\cos^2 \theta}}+t^2} \over {1+r^2}} r dt d\theta dr$?

I have found ${{\pi} \over {2}} \int_{0}^{+\infty} (e^{\alpha t} - \log(1+e^{{\alpha t}\over {2}})) dt+\pi \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^2\log(1+e^{\alpha t}) dt$

How can i prove is finited?

Comment: You need parentheses on the first integrand in the last line.

Comment: The domain contains the solid cylinder $D \times [0,\infty)\},$ where $D$ is the unit disc If you fix $(x,y)\in D$, the $t$ integral is $\infty,$ so the integral diverges to $\infty.$

Comment: if $\alpha =0$ ${{\pi} \over {2}} \int_{0}^{+\infty} (1 - \log(2)) dt+\pi \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^2\log(2) dt=+\infty$. But for $\alpha >0$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $D$ be the closed unit disc. Then $\Omega_\alpha$ contains $D\times [0,\infty)$ for every $\alpha \ge 0.$ On $D\times [0,\infty),$ the integrand is a least $t^2/2.$ Clearly

$$\int_{D\times [0,\infty)} \frac{t^2}{2} \,dt\, dx\,dy = \infty,$$

so your integral always diverges to $\infty.$

Comment: so $\int_{D\times[0,+\infty]} f(x,y,t) \,dx\, dy\, dt\ge \int_{D\times[0,+\infty]}\frac{t^2}{2} \,dx\, dy\, dt\ =+\infty $?

Comment: Yes. $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$